# Appropriate method to get time of server computer?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I do have my program running in a network. I have set one main computer as server and installed database system too. My other clients create transaction and saves it to database. Now I need to add date and time of server too in that record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running on the server, you can get the local time through the [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx#Y0) property.

If your application is only running on the client and you have no server-side application, only the database, you can include [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) or the `GETDATE()` function to you SQL statement. (Assuming you're running SQL Server).

Comment: the second option worked well... searching for ideas of running application on server and getting data from it